# How can I put an image with the Asset Manager into a IplImage?

Tags: android, image, javacv, iplimage, asset-management

I have a problem with my pictures which need to be loaded. The problem is that they are in the asset folder and I tried to load them with the path:

```
static String objectFilename = "file:///android_asset/sblinksoben.png";
```

After that I tried to load it into a IplImage:

```
static IplImage object;
object = cvLoadImage(objectFilename,
                    CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Everytime when I check it with the debugger it only stands: object = null.

I don't know how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
static IplImage object;
 static
    {
        object = cvLoadImage(objectFilename,
                    CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    }
```